# Unlist dataframes but also keep the original

Tags: r

I have the following data which i wish to unlist to make a new dataframe, probably easier here if i show show what im looking for; so i currently have names and codes like this;

```
name                          code
joe blogs/john williams       100000/100001
```

what i want:

```
name                          code
joe blogs                     1000000
john williams                 1000001
joe blogs/john williams       100000/100001
```

so im unlisting the original but also keeping it whilst making a new df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this may work for you

```
rbind(data.frame(sapply(df, strsplit, "/")), df)
                     name          code
1               joe blogs        100000
2           john williams        100001
3 joe blogs/john williams 100000/100001
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(name = "joe blogs/john williams", code = "100000/100001"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seperate_rows()` for that:

```
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  df <- data.frame(name = "joe blogs/john williams", 
                   code = "100000/100001") 
  
  df |> 
    separate_rows(everything(), sep = "/") |> 
    bind_rows(df)

# A tibble: 3 × 2
  name                    code         
  <chr>                   <chr>        
1 joe blogs               100000       
2 john williams           100001       
3 joe blogs/john williams 100000/100001
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `reframe`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  reframe(across(everything(), ~ c(unlist(strsplit(.x, "/")), .x)))
```

-output

```
                    name          code
1               joe blogs        100000
2           john williams        100001
3 joe blogs/john williams 100000/100001
```